# What should we do with experienced users who constantly use slang and shorthand?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, user-experience

I was browsing some questions earlier, and I happened across this post (revision 1 is in question here):

[Add a magnifier in cocos2d games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174882/)

I noticed that it was a very low quality for an experienced user (> 2k rep). So, I decided to check his profile:

[AppleVijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675170/applevijay)

And I noticed that many other of his answers (exibit [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531799/why-is-nslog-causing-exc-bad-access/7531862#7531862), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528886/saving-files-with-slash-in-file-name-objective-c/7528970#7528970), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555187/string-to-double/7555257#7555257)) have the same style (simple code blocks, letting others format his code for him, etc.).

I have nothing against this user, and, for the most part, his answers are good, but posters like him really detract from the professionalism that SO provides.

I would be more understanding if he was brand new to the site, but seeing as he's a user with over a year of experience and has over 450 answers, should we attempt to do something, other than meticulously go over his posts and attempt to improve them?

There's something to be said for moderating, but when users like this show no improvement over their time here (and encourage others to act in similar manner), I think action should be taken. After all, the last thing that SO needs is a bunch of users posting in texting 'slang' and making posts difficult to read, right?

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Yes, I understand that this man's first language is NOT english, but that's not the issue here. My concerns revolve around the site's continuing trend towards less and less care for grammar and etiquette.</sub>

Comment: Point them to the [English Language and Usage site](http://english.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @casperOne not a bad idea, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Just to be clear, it was meant more in jest as a knee-jerk reaction to the title, for comedic effect.  If I thought it was a good answer, I'd provide a full on answer.

Comment: @Rich, I was more than ready to stand for casperOne and try to provide an appropriate answer, but then you lost me. What exactly do you mean by `encourage others to act in similar manner`? I can see no incentive that would `encourage` others to the point of disrupting the site.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if you look at the comments on some of that user's posts, low-rep askers begin to post with similar bad grammar, and then the seeds are planted.

Comment: @Rich, well, our aim is to mow the lawn twice a week, so to speak, so planted seeds cannot grow. That said, you're really taking the broken windows paradigm to an all new level here. Every user has his own voice, the others are not sheep and, again, I cannot see how the behavior of the user you singled out could lead others in such a way as to disrupt the site.

Comment: Have you tried commenting on his answers in a constructive way, suggesting he not use "u" and "ur", but "you" and "your", etc.? He's been here a while, but maybe no one has pointed out to him the problems here and he's unaware that he's doing anything wrong. I know several people who learned English by reading comments and chat online, and had no idea that txtspeak wasn't how people really wrote.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, I did. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6189572/427309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just looked at some of his old answers from 2011. 3 or 4 of the older ones I looked at did have severe code formatting problems... none...

However, I sorted his answers and looked at the 10 newest answers. While 2 of them were one-liners that I'd personally be tempted to convert to comments, the rest of the answers do use valid code formatting, so it appears that the guy did finally start to take the hint.

As far as grammar goes, you might leave a comment and suggest he use better grammar, but I wouldn't expect it. In my experience, this is a cultural issue where not everyone views good grammar as a distinction that marks someone as a professional.

Luckily, this isn't a forum, and posts are editable. So as long as the edits are substantial, it's okay for us to fix these posts ourselves.

Comment: Did you flag those for NAA?  If they are comments, then so be it.

Comment: @casperOne - On one of them, the op said "your answer didn't work" but he had accepted it, which was odd. I asked him why, and after a vague non-explanation, he unaccepted it. I flagged that one as NAA, after the op unaccepted it. But the other one was also accepted, and I'm still not entirely sure how to handle the ones that are accepted. I've flagged them before and had them be marked as helpful, the accept removed, and the answer deleted, and I've also flagged them and seen no action taken....